# What does "piecewise definition ... is not a characteristic of the function itself" mean when referring to piecewise-defined functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I was reading the [Wikipedia page on piecewise-defined functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise) when, in the introduction, it states,

> Piecewise definition is actually a way of expressing the function, rather than a characteristic of the function itself.

which I don't understand. If the only method of expressing a function is as a piecewise-defined function, doesn't this make it a characteristic of the function? In other words, isn't being "piecewise" a characteristic of a "piecewise-defined" function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one can define the identity function $id:\Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb R$ as a piecewise function such as $id(x)=x$ for $x\geq 0$ and $id(x)=x$ for $x<0$. But this is not a characteristic of the function.

Comment: Perfect choice of an example and a concise explanation. Thank you and answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

A function is, depending on the choice your teachers made, either:

- a set $f$ such that $\forall z \in f,\ \exists x,y,\ z = (x,y)$ and for every $x,y,y'$, if $(x,y) \in f$ and $(x,y') \in f$, then $y=y'$;
- a triple $(E,F,f)$ where $f$ is as above, and $f\subset E \times F$, and $\forall x \in E,\ \exists y \in F,\ (x,y) \in F$.

I have never heard of a precise definition of what it means, for a function $f$, to "not be definable without a piecewise expression".

For example, do you think that $+ : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ can be defined in a "nonpiecewise manner"? My definition of this function is a definition by induction: if $y = 0$, then $x+y = x$, and for every $z$ such that $y = z+1$, $x+y = x+z+1$. Is this a piecewise definition?